# Jewelry render engine on webGL But not getting required quality

Tags: dictionary, textures, rendering, webgl

[image]http://dcotoz.com/misc/jewelry/index.html
We are trying to develop a jewelry 3D viewer with texture map (Gold). However we are not getting the required Gold realistic effect (please refer to the screenshot) where the rendering is jagged. Is there a problem with texture map, or UV mapping?

Comment: It looks very smooth on my computer. Try using `SmoothShading` shading param if you have such problems. It will avoid flat shading style. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463259/ssao-artefacts-in-three/18472004#18472004

Comment: It looks smooth on my computer as well.

Comment: Smooth here as whel: http://imgur.com/LHqAlaf

Comment: yes but its still not giving Gold realistic looks it looks painted